# How do I return a variable from Javascript to PHP for using it for a query "onchange"?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#p").change(function () {
    var p_id = $(this).val();
    console.log(p_id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "m/a/a.class.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {pId: p_id},

        success: function (data)
        {
            console.log(data); //<------ this gives me an empty output
            alert("success!");
        }
    });

   });
});
```

I am trying to get a the id of a selected value out of the selectpicker, when i change the selectpicker, i get the alert "success!" and in the console it shows the result, which is correct. When i want to use this result in PHP, which i am using ajax for, it gives me an odd output so i can't use the variable for the following sql statement.

What am i doing wrong? For you to understand i want to get the post input for product, so i can filter the next selectpicker by the id of "product", so i want to get dependant selectpicker "onchange". I already read many other questions, and it works in other examples when i use something like this in the success function:

```
success: function (data)
            {
                $('#state').html(data);
            }
```

But this isn't working for my example here, because when i use the "$_POST['produkt_id']" it either gives me an empty query or it has a mistake in it, since it passes the data from my screenshot. Thanks in advance and feel free to ask questions.

UPDATE:

This is where I am trying to get the previous input.

```
case 'linie':
            if(isset($_POST['pId'])) {
                $t = $_POST['pId'];
                $sql = 'SELECT id, bezeichnung  '
                    . 'FROM l "
                    . 'LEFT JOIN ' .produkte p ON p.id=l.p_id '
                    . 'WHERE l.p_id =' . "$t" . 'AND l.deleted=0 AND p.deleted=0 '
                    . 'ORDER BY l.bezeichnung ';
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

the error says it. PHP you're using is calling "include_once" and the file which you're trying to include, doesn't exist.
that makes the PHP to return a response with error in it, and the response - because of that error text - is not a valid JSON anymore.

Comment: But the file exists, and i can use the functions of it, but only in the console it shows a wrong path where it tries to find the file in the same path as "ausschuss.class.php". In the PHP file it has another path.

Comment: the file may exist, but the actual path may be different. (you're using relative path which may be different every time you call the script from different folder)

Comment: okay i changed all the paths now, as you said it was the problem with the relative paths, but now the "console.log(data)" is empty. Do you know how i can get this data into my php file so i can use it for a query?

Comment: please attach the PHP output to the question and I'll try to tell you what's wrong. previously there was PHP error which was source of the problem. now I need to see what's the non-error output that's causing you issues.

Comment: first of all, confirm the `case` statement actually gets into the if statement, then output (var_dump is fine for this) the full query. pinpoint the place where it's wrong. is only the POST variable wrong? or maybe you don't even get inside the if statement?
and FYI: you still didn't add the PHP output into the question, you can look it up in your browser network tab (if you're using chrome developer tools).
mght be you're failing to query `modules/ausschuss/ausschuss.class.php` because that's not absolute URL and that's where the problem really is - your javascript

Comment: It seems like you're right the URL must be wrong, doesn't it just have to be the URL to the file where i want to use the ajax data?

Comment: the URL is relative to the page you're currently on. i.e
if you're on `http://example.com/myproject/mypage` the absolute url will be
`http://example.com/myproject/mypagemodules/ausschuss/ausschuss.class.php` (note no slash between mypage and modules). you need ot figure that out for your config first
better to add slash at the jQuery AJAX url so it's counted from the http://example.com (domain), not from the url you're currently on. the Jquery AJAX should have a slash at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax code you should put your url route path for file request it hink you put the file path of your project system that's why your ajax file could not find and include your file for ajax request execution

```
$.ajax({
        url: "modules/ausschuss/ausschuss.class.php", //remove this
        url: "full url for your file execution"

        method: "POST",
        data: {produkt_id: produkt_id},

        success: function (data)
        {
            alert("success!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used the url to the file where i request the $_POST variable

Comment: then your calling file fail to include file please check it again

Comment: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ausschuss-tool\modules\ausschuss\ausschuss.class.php
The file is in C:\xampp\htdocs\ctb\ctb.class.php, using PHP i don't get an error, but i get it here, so how can i change the path for JS?
Nevertheless my question was why doesn't it send the same as "console.log(produkt_id);"?